# Installing geograpy3 on windows

Tags: python-3.x, installation, geograpy

I cannot manage to get the geograpy3 module running in my PC because I could not successfully install it as detailed in the "Install & Setup" section of the project description website (https://pypi.org/project/geograpy3/)
I am guessing the problem might be that my operating system is Windows and the install script is in another language. Are these files available also for Windows? Or is there another way to bypass these commands that you described in the website? I would really appreciate any help / indication that you could give me to solve this problem!
Thanks in advance,
Emilia

Comment: Any error messages you can share during your installation?

Comment: scripts/install is indeed a bash script which is just a convenience and used for Continuous integration testing (in Ubuntu, MacOS and Windows!). You can just issue the two necessary commands pip install ... and geograpy-nltk one after another.

Answer (score 1):

You should try updating your `pip3` to the latest version. Also, please try to add more information about the exact error that is keeping you from successful installation. Make sure your Windows machine has `python3` installed as there are no other installation requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Please try running `pip3 install geograpy3`.

Since the library is tested in Windows, it should run there.